# Hibernate Validation + Custom Constraint + java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I'have been fighting with this for days, I've read all the discussions here but with no solution...

I have a custom constraint..

**Unique.java**

```
@Target({FIELD, METHOD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = UniqueConstraintValidator.class)
public @interface Unique {

    String message() default "{src.main.resources}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    String property() default "id";

    Class<?> entity();

}
```

This is used by **UniqueConstraintValidator.java**

```
@Transactional
public class UniqueConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Unique, Serializable> {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UniqueConstraintValidator.class);
    Session session;


    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected Session getSession(){
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}

    private Class<?> entityClass;
    private String uniqueField;

    public void initialize(Unique unique) {
        entityClass = unique.entity();
        uniqueField = unique.property();

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public boolean isValid(Serializable property, ConstraintValidatorContext cvContext) {

        String query = String.format("from %s where %s = :field ", entityClass.getName(), uniqueField);
        List list = getSession().createQuery(query).setParameter("field", property).list();
        return list != null && list.size() == 0;
    }

}
```

Now, my model has this annotation where I need to validate the uniqueness of the field

```
@NotNull
@Unique(entity = Luce.class, property="numeroLuce")
@Column(name="numero_luce")
public int getNumeroLuce() {
    return numeroLuce;
}

public void setNumeroLuce(int numeroLuce) {
    this.numeroLuce = numeroLuce;
}
```

Now, i know the custom annotation won't work while updating an existing object, but now i need to understand how it works.
Let's assume we want to add a new object.

When I try to save an already existing value, I got a correct validation error but if I want to save a valid object i got a `java.lang.NullPointerException`

*EDITED* this is the full stacktrace

```
    exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call.
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call.
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:286)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:133)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:91)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:83)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:547)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:487)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:451)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:403)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:206)
    org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:137)
    org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:95)
    org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:214)
    org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:92)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:490)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:195)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:179)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:214)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
    it.besmart.dao.AbstractDao.persist(AbstractDao.java:37)
    it.besmart.dao.LuceDaoImpl.saveLuci(LuceDaoImpl.java:33)
    it.besmart.service.LuceServiceImpl.saveLuci(LuceServiceImpl.java:33)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48.saveLuci(Unknown Source)
    it.besmart.controller.LuceController.saveLight(LuceController.java:87)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    it.besmart.validator.UniqueConstraintValidator.getSession(UniqueConstraintValidator.java:27)
    it.besmart.validator.UniqueConstraintValidator.isValid(UniqueConstraintValidator.java:44)
    it.besmart.validator.UniqueConstraintValidator.isValid(UniqueConstraintValidator.java:18)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:283)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:133)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:91)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:83)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:547)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:487)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:451)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:403)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:206)
    org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:137)
    org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:95)
    org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:214)
    org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:92)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:490)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:195)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:179)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:214)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
    it.besmart.dao.AbstractDao.persist(AbstractDao.java:37)
    it.besmart.dao.LuceDaoImpl.saveLuci(LuceDaoImpl.java:33)
    it.besmart.service.LuceServiceImpl.saveLuci(LuceServiceImpl.java:33)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48.saveLuci(Unknown Source)
    it.besmart.controller.LuceController.saveLight(LuceController.java:87)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I really cannot understand what I'm doing wrong, i know i'm a java noob, but everything looks to me correct.

I added a log in **UniqueConstraintValidator** to check if sessionFactory is null, but i'm getting

```
Session is org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@53911200
```

so, it's not null...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using Spring Framework, right? Add it to the tags, please.

Comment: Looks like `sessionFactory` is `null` and it wasn't auto wired.

Comment: I don't know if it's null because the exception comes before my logger.. But, if sessionFactory is null, it means that is null also when trying to validate a correct value, right? But i'm not getting the exception in that case... PS i added the tag, thanks

Comment: added a correct log, sessionFactory is not null...

Comment: please debug your code and check where the nullpointer exception occurs.

Comment: Thanks @Simo I'm trying to look form the exception, but everything doesn't give me a null pointer... sessionFactory is not null everywhere in the process

Comment: that is weird, ocurrs the nullpointer in the log while debugging? that can't be

Comment: please post the full stacktrace

Comment: added it, thanks, i put a logger to check for null values in every class of my project that is involved in the stacktrace

Comment: so the problem comes only when isValid is true, so it should go on and save the new Object... Clearly, if I comment the @Unique annotation, the object is saved normally... So it must be something that happens only after isValid is called...

Answer (score 1):

In this comment You will find answer.

[JSR303 custom validators being called twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24955817/jsr303-custom-validators-being-called-twice)

First you validate object by spring when is create by form, and second time by hibernate before persistence (it's default behavior). As I understood hibernate make validation outside Spring context so Autowired doesn't work. That is why you get NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

By this line:

```
it.besmart.validator.UniqueConstraintValidator.getSession(UniqueConstraintValidator.java:27)
```

it is saying that `getSession()` throws a NPE. I guess `getSession()`, if is the line 27, does not find `sessionFactory`. `@Autowired` is not working here.

And, I actually doubt the decision of mixing the validator with business logic; the validator should return `true` when the incoming value is good, and `false` if is bad; nothing more. You should not make it `@Transactional` and saving things into DB. No, code smell against SRP.