# Using I18n messages while validating forms with JSR-303

Tags: java, spring, validation, internationalization

My app is fully-configured spring-boot app with thymeleaf templates engine. I18n configured as well so I can use it within my templates. Here is the config I use:

```
spring.messages.basename=i18n/messages
```

While manual validating fields I18n also work fine:

```
BindingResult result;
result.rejectValue("field", "some.i18n.code");
```

But once I want to implement some custom `ConstraintValidator` objects and use `message` field - no I18n involved, I receive plain codes as a response instead of a message. I.e.

```
{some.i18n.code}
```

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23615478/705869) - no result.
[This on](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#section-message-interpolation) as well - same result.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I found the solution, maybe it will be helpful to others. All you have to do is to add the following definitions into your `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` configuration implementation:

```
@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;

@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
     LocalValidatorFactoryBean validatorFactoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
     validatorFactoryBean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource);

     return validatorFactoryBean;
}

@Override
public Validator getValidator() {
     return validator();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution is just declare this bean in any of your `@Configuration` classes:

```
@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean(MessageSource messageSource) {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    bean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource);
    return bean;
}
```

Due to declaring this, now my custom error codes from my custom validators are being searched for in my `messages.properties` (that I also have in a `i18n` subdirectory by declaring `spring.messages.basename=i18n/messages`).

Example validator code:

```
public class ContestValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidContest, CreateContestParameters> {

  @Override
  public void initialize(ValidContest constraintAnnotation) {

  }

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(CreateContestParameters contestParameters, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    boolean result = true;

    if (!endDateIsEqualOrAfterStartDate(contestParameters)) {
        context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("{Contest.endDate.invalid}")
               .addPropertyNode("endDate").addConstraintViolation();
        result = false;
    }
    if (!registrationDeadlineIsBeforeStartDate(contestParameters)) {
        context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("{Contest.registrationDeadline.invalid}")
               .addPropertyNode("registrationDeadline").addConstraintViolation();
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```