# How to use Java Beans validation through hibernate-validation without a framework?

Tags: java, hibernate-validator

I'm using Java Beans validation through hibernate-validation on a JavaFX application, so, without a framework to help with the wiring. I added these dependencies to my project:

```
compile group: "org.hibernate", name: "hibernate-validator", version: "6.0.2.Final"
compile group: "org.glassfish", name: "javax.el", version: "3.0.1-b08"
compile group: "javax.validation", name: "validation-api", version: "2.0.0.Final"
```

and I found this works to get `modelObject` validated:

```
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
validator.validate(modelObject);
```

My question is, is it bad to create a new factory and validator every time I validate? Should I cache them somewhere and re-use them? How expensive and how multi-threaded are the validators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is it bad to create new `ValidatorFactory` each time?

According to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/Validation.html) note, the following is stated:

> - The ValidatorFactory object built by the bootstrap process **should be cached and shared amongst Validator consumers**.
> - This class is thread-safe.

As of `Validator`, its implementations also expected to be **thread-safe** according to [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/Validator.html)

#### Working with javax.Validation in Spring

You've tagged your question with 'Spring', therefore a brief notice on working with javax.validation + Spring correctly.

First, use Spring `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` (as for example answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23615478/8513835)), that will take care of necessary caching you're looking for:

```
@Bean
public javax.validation.Validator localValidatorFactoryBean() {
   return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
}
```

Second, inject Validator instances using Spring as well:

```
@Autowired
private Validator validator;
```

You can either let Spring do all the job. For example, to make validation-related annotations work for methods, define

```
@Bean
public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
    return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
}
```

in your Spring application configuration, and then you'll be able to call something like

```
public void myMethod(@Valid MyValidationAnnotatedType parameter){
    ...
}

public void anotherMethod(@Pattern(regex = "^[A-Za-z]+$") stringParameter) {
    ...
}
```

Please refer to [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation) for further details

Comment: Thank you for the pointers to the JavaDoc... I shouldn't have missed that. Regarding Spring, that was a mistake, so I removed the tag, but the server side is running Spring, so, that'll be useful anyway :)